# LINQ expression with generic class properties

Tags: c#, linq, generics, lambda

I would like to pass an IQueryable and an array of ids to a method which filters the IQueryable based on those ids.

As the ids can be either long's or int's it should be solved generically.

I came up with the following:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetModified<TId, T>(IQueryable<T> objects, TId[] ids) where T : class
{
        return objects.Where(j => ids.Contains((TId)j.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(j)));
}
```

Unfortunately I'm getting the exception:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object GetValue(System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exception is normal, as getting properties through reflection is something that clearly cannot be translated to SQL.

One thing I would try is to create a generic interface that exposes an `Id` property of a given type:

```
public interface HasId<T> {
    T Id { get; set; }
}
```

Now you could declare your entity as implementing `HasId<int>`, for example, if the `Id` was of type `int`.

The next step is to modify your method like so:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetModified<TId, T>
    (IQueryable<T> objects, TId[] ids) where T : class, HasId<TId>
{
    return objects.Where(j => ids.Contains(j.Id));
}
```

Note the added generic restriction: `where T : class, HasId<TId>`. This enables you to write the simplified `j.Id`, which returns a `TId` value, instead of resorting to reflection.

Please note that I haven't run or tested this code; it's just an idea that I got when I saw your problem and I hope it helps.

#### Update:

Here's another possible solution that doesn't require that you declare interfaces or change your classes in any way:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetModified<TId, T>
    (IQueryable<T> objects, TId[] ids, Expression<Func<T, TId>> idSelector) 
    where T : class
{
    return objects.Where(j => ids.Contains(idSelector(j)));
}
```

What I've done here is add the `Expression<Func<T, TId>> idSelector` parameter, an expression that can return the `Id` of a given instance of `T`.

You would call the method like that:

```
var modified = GetModified(dbObjects, yourIdArray, entity => entity.Id);
```

(only the third parameter being new; keep the others as you have them now).

Again, I haven't tested if this works or even compiles, as I don't have a computer with VS here :(.

Comment: dear sir, this is answer is great! i haven't tried the second approach but the first one works like a charm.

Comment: The second approach does not work as expected. Error: 'idSelector' is a variable but is used like a method.

Comment: I asked another question related to the second approach. If you are interested see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933314/linq-expression-with-generic-property

Answer (score 3):

Entity Framework doesn't support some of the .NET methods such as `GetValue()` since it does not translate to SQL (which is the code actually executed to the `IQueryable`. Try calling `ToList` to get the CLR object before doing reflection:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetModified<TId, T>(IQueryable<T> objects, TId[] ids) where T : class
{
    return objects.ToList().Where(j => ids.Contains((TId)j.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(j)));
}
```

Comment: this works but is very inefficient because all objects are pulled from the database right?

Comment: That is correct. But since you require reflection, there is no way for LINQ to Entites to translate your reflection code into SQL. I guess you can try `objects.Cast<TId>().Where(a => ids.Contains(a.Id))`