# LINQ expression with generic property

Tags: c#, linq, generics, lambda

My question is related to this one: [linq-expression-with-generic-class-properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18930503/linq-expression-with-generic-class-properties)

This time I would like to get newly created objects which have the id in common. The id is in fact the foreign key and therefore can have different names.

I came up with the following:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetNew<TId, T>(IQueryable<T> objects, TId id, DateTime date, Expression<Func<T, TId>> idSelector) 
    where T : class, ISyncable<TId>
{
    return objects.Where(o => idSelector(o) == id && o.CreatedDate > date);
}
```

The method would be called like this:

```
var modified = GetNew(dbObjects, id, date, entity => entity.PersonId);
```

Unfortunately I get the error:

```
'idSelector' is a variable but is used like a method.
```

The expression passed to the method should do something like that:

```
objects.Where(o => o.PersonId == id && o.CreatedDate > date);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to build a new expression representing the condition and pass that to `Where`:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetNew<TId, T>(IQueryable<T> objects, TId id, DateTime date, Expression<Func<T, TId>> idSelector)
    where T : class, ISyncable<TId>
{
    var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var idEqExpr = Expression.Equal(Expression.Invoke(idSelector, paramExpr), Expression.Constant(id));
    var createdPropExpr = Expression.Property(paramExpr, "CreatedDate");
    var gtExpr = Expression.GreaterThan(createdPropExpr, Expression.Constant(date));
    var andExpr = Expression.And(idEqExpr, gtExpr);

    var condExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(andExpr, paramExpr);

    return objects.Where(condExpr);
}
```

EDIT: If you know that the `idSelector` is a property expression, you could extract the referenced property and create a new property expression instead of using `Invoke`:

```
var idProperty = (PropertyInfo)((MemberExpression)idSelector.Body).Member;
var idEqExpr = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(paramExpr, idProperty), Expression.Constant(id));
```

Comment: Or call `Where` method twice.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm getting the exception: The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Is there no way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: @Moo - If you expect `idSelector` is a property expression you could use that instead of `Invoke`. If you can't do that, you'll have to try and deconstruct it recursively and build a new expression that doesn't use `Invoke`. See update.

Comment: @Lee I have built an expression kind of like you describe. It works great for e.g LessThan or GreaterThan expressions. But if I add two expressions together, it uses the '&' sign, I require it to be the string 'AND'. Can you tell me how to fix this, please?

Comment: @Jones - Could you create a new question with an example? It sounds like you're trying to convert an expression into query string in which case you might be able to create an [ExpressionVisitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expressionvisitor?view=net-5.0) to traverse the expression and convert each node into a string representation.

Comment: @Lee Hi Lee, I have discovered that I must use `.AndAlso`, then I get the correct behavior:
`// Combine expressions using AndAlso => 'AND' operand. Do not use And => '&'
queryExpression = Expression.AndAlso(smallerExp, largerExp);`
Thank you!