# Linq over generic class with generic property

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, generics

The issue is about getting the Max value within a sequence of elements. 
The type of the object is unknown and the property follows the convention `<EntityName>_Id`.

At the moment I resolved it like this:

```
public static int GetMaxId<TEntity>()
{
    try
    {
        var key = typeof(TEntity).Name;
        var adapter = (IObjectContextAdapter)MyDbContext;
        var objectContext = adapter.ObjectContext;
        // 1. we need the container for the conceptual model
        var container = objectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetEntityContainer(
            objectContext.DefaultContainerName, System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.DataSpace.CSpace);
        // 2. we need the name given to the element set in that conceptual model
        var name = container.BaseEntitySets.Where((s) => s.ElementType.Name.Equals(key)).FirstOrDefault().Name;
        // 3. finally, we can create a basic query for this set
        var query = objectContext.CreateQuery<TEntity>("[" + name + "]");

        // working with result
        var baseEntity = container.BaseEntitySets.Where((s) => s.ElementType.Name.Equals(key)).FirstOrDefault();
        var property = baseEntity.ElementType.Members.FirstOrDefault(_property => _property.Name.EndsWith("Id"));

        var tmpResult = query.ToList();

        var currentMaxID = tmpResult.Max(element =>
        {
            PropertyInfo pInfo = typeof(TEntity).GetProperty(property.Name);
            int value = (int)pInfo.GetValue(element);

            return value;
        });

        return currentMaxID;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string exMessage = "GetMaxId.Exception";
        EntityModelDataProviderLogger.Fatal(exMessage, ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Is there a better/cleaner way to do it?

I have read about dynamic Expressions but it wasn't so clear to me.

[LINQ expression with generic property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933314/linq-expression-with-generic-property) This example compares Dates. In my case I have "only one element" and I don't know how to construct the expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite long, and I can't test it here:

```
public static int GetMaxId<TEntity>()
{
    try
    {
        var key = typeof(TEntity).Name;
        var adapter = (IObjectContextAdapter)MyDbContext;
        var objectContext = adapter.ObjectContext;

        // 1. we need the container for the conceptual model
        var container = objectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetEntityContainer(
            objectContext.DefaultContainerName, System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.DataSpace.CSpace);
        // 2. we need the name given to the element set in that conceptual model
        var baseEntity = container.BaseEntitySets.Single(s => s.ElementType.Name == key);
        // 3. finally, we can create a basic query for this set
        var query = objectContext.CreateQuery<TEntity>("[" + baseEntity.Name + "]");

        // Looking for the property
        string propertyId = baseEntity.Name + "_" + "Id";
        // The PropertyInfo connected to the EdmMember
        PropertyInfo property = (PropertyInfo)typeof(TEntity).GetProperty(propertyId);

        // Building the Expression
        ParameterExpression par = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity));
        MemberExpression prop = Expression.Property(par, property);

        // cast to (int?)property
        // Note the use of int?, because the table could be empty!
        UnaryExpression conv = Expression.Convert(prop, typeof(int?));

        // An expression like x => x.Entity_Id
        Expression<Func<TEntity, int?>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, int?>>(conv, par);

        int? currentMaxID = ((IQueryable<TEntity>)query).Max(lambda);

        // We change null to 0
        return currentMaxID ?? 0;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string exMessage = "GetMaxId.Exception";
        EntityModelDataProviderLogger.Fatal(exMessage, ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

If it works I'll explain how/why it works...

Note that what you were doing is **conceptually wrong**... You where SELECTing all the table with the `ToList()` and then locally looking for the `Max()`. This code instead creates an Expression Tree to do the `Max()` database-side.

Comment: This line `PropertyInfo property = (PropertyInfo)edmMember.MetadataProperties.Single(x => x.Name == "ClrPropertyInfo").Value;` throws exception. I inspected the `MetadataProperties` and it contains three elements in my test case(names: Name, TypeUsage, MetadataProperties)

Comment: @blacai Using directly reflection. Try now.

Comment: I wouldn't say "conceptually wrong". There is no issue with speed here, only memory. I question the value of writing 60 lines of C# over what can be done in 1 line of sql anyway.

Comment: Why would you search for the Max method by reflection if you already know its type parameters at compile-time?

Comment: @Georg Because you are right! :-) Sometimes one has a mindset, and goes like a train... will correct in 5 minutes

Comment: @Georg The truth is that I was building a method able to work with an "unknown" type of id (so for example with a `long` id)... So I mixed everything...

Answer (score 0):

I would define an interface with property Id and add a constraint on your method to only accept types of that interface. That removes the need for fragile naming conventions and makes reflection unnecessary.

```
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public static int GetMaxId<TEntity>() where TEntity : IEntity
{
    return MyDbContext.Set<TEntity>().AsEnumerable().Max(e => e.Id);
}

public Entity : IEntity
{
    public int MyId { get; set;}

    public int Id { get{ return MyId; } set{ MyId = value; } }
}
```

Usage:

```
var max = GetMaxId<Entity>();
```

Comment: With this solution, I should have to modify all the classes generated by EntityFramework, to implement the Interface, right?

Comment: Any class you plan to use this method for yes.

Comment: There is a way to do it by just grabbing out the entity key and comparing them I can't find the example currently

Comment: @Shoe It isn't clear why there are two `Id` (`Id` and `MyId`)... Which one of the two should be mapped to the Db? And what is the use of the other one?

Comment: @xanatos `MyId` is the db mapped Id. `Id` comes from the interface. The interface provides the means to have any name for an Id field instead of keeping track of an arbitrary convention.

Comment: @Shoe You can't use a `IQueryable<>` on an unmapped property (`Id`) like this: `MyDbContext.Set<TEntity>().Max(e => e.Id)`. You could do a `MyDbContext.Set<TEntity>().AsEnumerable().Max(e => e.Id)`

Comment: @xanatos Probably true. I never tested this :)